# Is there a new upcoming C Standard that supersedes C99?

Tags: c

Is there a new upcoming C Standard that supersedes C99? After all there's an unofficial C++0x coming out as per the source in Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x). For the sake of this question, let's call  this C99 superset as C'y2k.01' to not confuse (as I was going to say C99++ which looks like the C++ counterpart.... but I digress)

If there isn't, what would you like to see in the C'y2k.01' standard today in order for the C language to survive in the 21st century? Sure there's Java, .NET, C#, Scala, Erlang, F# to name but a few, but really, go on...

I would like to see:

1. Unifying the Posix functions into the runtime,
2. with the #1 mentioned above, `fork()`ing would be much easier and parallelizing the code would be made possible instead of relying on a third party library
3. The ease of dynamic memory for custom collections such as arrays ... something like this 'char __dynamic foo[];' where you can add/remove elements easily

This is open to debate and discussion.

Thanks.

Comment: What POSIX functions are you talking about specifically? Note, that POSIX is only compatible with C in restrictive sense, i.e. POSIX requires a specific version of C (expectedly, aligned with Unix specifics). For this raeson, it is not possible to integrate POSIX into C without destroying POSIX.

Comment: "C'y2k.01'"??? Why not call it c1x like the rest of us? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I did not know from the answers below that C1X is coming out....sorry for the long winded 'Cy2k.01'....how was I to know that... :)

Comment: Ok..Should I modify this question to say the next one after C1X to make it more interesting?

Comment: You'd be better off asking _another_ question for that one, @tommieb75.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a project in place to update C99. The draft is currently dubbed [C1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) and is available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1425.pdf). You can also see the [charter](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1250.pdf).

You can see a list of the currently open [projects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects) and get up to date news from the [ISO C Working Group](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).